# Partial application of TypeScript object

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I want to partially apply an object to a function that accepts a single object as argument. I have been able to make the `partial` function below return a function that behaves as expected, but I am not able to make the partial function reject extra keys for the provided `x`:

```js
/******
 * Things that I couldn't make work.
 */
type Impossible<K extends keyof any> = {
  [P in K]: never;
};

type NoExtraProperties<T, U extends T = T> = U & Impossible<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>>;

type Exactly<T, X> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof X, keyof T>, never>


/*********
 * Attempted implementation
 */
const partial = <T, X extends Partial<T> = Partial<T>>(fn: (arg: T) => unknown, x: X): ((arg: Omit<T, keyof X>) => ReturnType<typeof fn>) => {
    return (arg) => fn(Object.assign(x, arg) as T);
}

// Example function to partially apply
const fn = ({name, age, alive}: {name: string, age: number, alive: boolean}): string => {
    return name + age.toString()
}

// plain function call
const fullCallResult = fn({
    name: "Maono",
    //sadfadsfdas: "sdfadsfa", // Error here, as expected.
    age: 19,
    alive: true
});

const partialllyApplied = partial(fn, {
    name: "asdfasdf",
    sadfadsfdas: "sdfadsfa" // <- No error here. I want this to give an error.
    //, age: 32
    //, alive: true
});

const partialllyAppliedResult = partialllyApplied({agde: 44, alive: false}) // <-- Error here, good, there is a type.

const partialllyAppliedResult2 = partialllyApplied({age: 44, alive: false})
```

How could you make the `partial` function restrict what keys are accepted from the passed `x` object mimicking a direct function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function partialApply<T, R, X extends Partial<T>>(
    fn: (arg: T) => R,
    // X, but keyof T is not optional and unwanteds are never
    def: X & { [K in keyof X]-?: K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never }
    //      T, but keyof X is optional
): (rest: { [K in keyof (Omit<T, keyof X> & Partial<T>)]: T[K] }) => R {
    return function apply(rest) {
        // create new object, rest may override def
        return fn({ ...def, ...rest })
    }
}

// Example function to partially apply
const fn = ({ name, age, alive }: { name: string, age: number, alive: boolean }): string => {
    return name + age.toString();
}
const apply1 = partialApply(fn, { age: 123 })
//    ^?
// const apply1: (rest: {
//     name: string;
//     alive: boolean;
//     age?: number | undefined;
// }) => string

partialApply(fn, { age: 123 as 123 | undefined })
//                 ~~~ Type '123 | undefined' is not assignable to type '123'.
partialApply(fn, { age: 123 })({ alive: true })
//                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Property 'name' is missing in type '{ alive: true; }'
```